# Change app icons with only IPA file provided

Tags: ios, ipa

How can I change app icon after creating the ipa file?

I am following the below steps:

1. Rename the .ipa to .zip, and unzip the archive.
2. Inside should be a folder called "payload", and inside that folder should be your application archive.
3. Change the app icons file
4. Re-zip the archive
5. Rename the .zip to .ipa
6. Re-sign the .ipa

But the ipa is not installed. It shows Modified (add or delete) file error.

Comment: Yes, It is not possible

Comment: Do you have the source code of the .ipa file in your xcode, if you have , then there is hope.

Comment: This is possible and I do it regularly. The steps outlined above are correct. If the app isn't installing it is most likely a signing issue. Check the device logs when the install fails and it will tell you what the problem is.

Comment: @respectTheCode are you able to modify the icons within Assets.car file?

Comment: @CarlaCamargo Yes The icons modified success, But the ipa file not installed in device

Comment: @srinivasn  How have you modified the icons?

Comment: @CarlaCamargo The above process we are failed. Then we modified the icon files and created the IPA file through commands, for this we are using Xcode server and enterprise license 1. Change the icons first 2. Create ipa file using commands

Comment: I know how to change the icons outside de assets.car and create the ipa afterwards, my problem is change the icons inside de assets.car...

Comment: @CarlaCamargo look into this may be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47382404/creating-assets-car-file-through-command-line-for-app-resigning,   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47915805/update-ios-11-app-icons-in-assets-car-post-build

Answer (score 0):

1. Extract IPA (it contains the single `Payload` directory):

```
$ unzip MyApp.ipa
```

2. Print content of `Info.plist`

```
$ plutil -p ./Payload/MyApp.app/Info.plist

 "CFBundleIcons" => {
   "CFBundlePrimaryIcon" => {
     "CFBundleIconFiles" => [
       0 => "AppIcon60x60"
     ]
     "CFBundleIconName" => "AppIcon"
   }
 }
 "CFBundleIcons~ipad" => {
   "CFBundlePrimaryIcon" => {
     "CFBundleIconFiles" => [
       0 => "AppIcon60x60"
       1 => "AppIcon76x76"
     ]
     "CFBundleIconName" => "AppIcon"
   }
 }
```

3. Replace all listed icons in `./Payload/MyApp.app/` with new icons.
4. Zip modified `./Payload` to new IPA

```
$ zip -vr NewMyApp.ipa ./Payload
```

5. `NewMyApp.ipa` with new icons is ready for use

Comment: Aren't these basically the same steps listed in the question (minus resigning at the end)?

Comment: @HangarRash Sure this is same idea, but these steps are clear and reproducible (unlike of steps in the question). Resigning is unnecessarily because xcodebuild signs only binary execution files, not whole IPA.