# Creating Assets.car file through command line for app resigning

Tags: ios

My app is white labeled by building a generic app and then resigning the app bundle with new images. Before `iOS11` I could achieve this by switching in new images into the bundle and resigning. However now that asset catalogs are required for the app icons I'm having trouble creating the `Assets.car` file.

Here is what I have tried:

Copying `Images.xcassets` to a working directory (with a `build` directory next to it). `Images.xcassets` contains `AppIcons.appiconset` and `LaunchImage.launchimage`.

From the command line

```
xcrun actool Images.xcassets --compile build --platform iphoneos --minimum-deployment-target 9.0
```

It seems to run but no file is created.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.actool.compilation-results</key>
    <dict>
        <key>output-files</key>
        <array/>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I hope I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: I don't see you using the `--app-icon` and `--launch-image` options.

Comment: if you specify --app-icon AppIcons how you merge this other icon suppose if you have the others icons used in your app

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need to use the name of your `appiconset`.

So in this example add:

```
 --app-icon AppIcons --output-partial-info-plist build/partial.plist
```

Comment: if you specify --app-icon AppIcons how you merge this other icon suppose if you have the others icons used in your app

Comment: I'm having the same problem, how do I merge the AppIcons with the other assets to one Assets.car file?

Comment: use *.xcassets to merge them 
`xcrun actool --compile build *.xcassets --platform iphoneos --minimum-deployment-target 11.0 --app-icon AppIcon-Dev --output-partial-info-plist build/parital-dev.plist`

Comment: hello, could you please write a complete example? Detail explanation is appreciated. I'm new to xcrun actool command line. What does build mean? Is it a directory name? What should I write after --app-icon?

Comment: @AllDayer might be able to help.

Answer (score 5):

Have getting same issues, but after an hour R&D got success with the
below code:

```
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/actool Assets.xcassets --compile build --platform iphoneos  --minimum-deployment-target 9.0 --app-icon AppIcon --output-partial-info-plist  myfolder/info.plist
```

or

```
/usr/bin/xcrun actool Assets.xcassets --compile build --platform iphoneos --minimum-deployment-target 8.0 --app-icon AppIcon --output-partial-info-plist build/partial.plist
```

Where you can change platform value and output path {such as **myfolder/build** is folder name}