# Update iOS 11 App icons in assets.car post build

Tags: ios

I currently have an iOS project where I create a ipa with one set of app icons and then what I do ,post building in Xcode ,is unzip the ipa via a sh script copy some new app icons to the root level of the .app file ,change the app ID and resign it and this all works great until iOS 11 came along and I notice it would like for the icons to be in the assets.car file.

Does anyone know if it’s possible to update that assets.car file post build ,via a sh ideally ,with a new set of app icons without having to rebuild the project

Thanks in advance

Simon

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22630418/analysing-assets-car-file-in-ios

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47382404/creating-assets-car-file-through-command-line-for-app-resigning

Comment: Hi Thanks for the above I have tried a few things and I can't quite get it to work so what I did was Create a folder and in that folder copy in my existing images.assets folder. I then updated the icons to the new ones in Appicons.iconset. Then I created a build folder at the same level as the images.assets folder and ran `xcrun actool --compile build Images.xcassets --platform iphoneos --minimum-deployment-target 10.0 --app-icon AppIcon --output-partial-info-plist build/partial-info.plist` The assets.car file was created but the AppIcon.iconset wasn't updated with the new icons